# Show the Total Count of the column value generated using SPFx Field Customizer

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, count

I have developed a Field Customizer Extension. This renders the item count based on the logic for each cell in the Document Library.

Now, I want to show the total of the count at the bottom of the custom column.

[image]

How to show the count at the bottom using SPFx?

**Note: Here, the numbers in the count column are rendered using the Field Customizer. So OOTB Total functionality is not working on it.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about using SharePoint OOTB count which shows totals in the list view?

Comment: I have specific logic to get the count.So the numbers you are seeing in Red highlight are rendered using SPFx Extension. Hence, OOTB Total does not work on that as that is not the actual data